# Browser console elements are blinking like they are rendered although they are not, from unknow reason

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have some pages which use a common module on application. From unknow reason I keep seeing the tr's elements on the browser console blinking in a purple like they are rendered again.

I don't see reason for that behavior and it's unwanted.

How can I debug or check in another way what's causing it

See the attached image please

**EDIT:**
I've tried to add onChange life cycle to my component to see if there are changes that I'm not aware of. But it doesn't triggered at all (when this scenario happens)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that something in your code is constantly triggering the angular change detector. An example of such action can be wrong usage of some component lifecycle hook like *ngAfterViewChecked* or *ngDoCheck*.

Comment: But none of them exist in my code. Also I've added on change lifecycle to check if there are changes. It's not triggered.

Comment: *ngOnChange* is not triggered on DOM events. To check if the issue add the following to your components _.ts_ file and see how many times it runs: `ngAfterViewChecked() { console.log(123); }`

Comment: Thanks it does show the input a lot. Do you have an idea how to find the cause to that and stop it ? And is it's a problem in performance perspective

Comment: It's definitely a problem in performance perspective. How to find the source of it - need to see more code from the project. For example I saw in some project the code like this, which caused an issue like yours: `ngAfterViewChecked() { window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); }` It also might be some data polling that you do for your table and don't use _trackBy_. A lot of possible reasons.

Comment: Thanks, actually we are using CDK-virtual-scrolling from angular Mat mixed with some other 3rd party library. Maybe it's the cause, I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an `ngFor` of an array generated on your code, Angular cannot identify and element as unique. If this is the case, you can add the trackBy functionality to let Angular known a unique key per item and avoid to keep render the items.

[Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction)

[Example](https://tharakamd-12.medium.com/avoid-unnecessary-rendering-on-angular-ngfor-with-trackby-f56ae5d79561)